# how to get the confusion matrix and classification report for CNN model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have been trying to implement CNN with the data set the shape of  (2830743, 79). the following code is to split the dataset. I have done one hot encoder to encode the target labels.

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, StandardScaler, LabelEncoder

X = data_np[:, 0:78]

enc = OneHotEncoder()


Y = enc.fit_transform(data_np[:,79:]).toarray()

# Scale data to have mean 0 and variance 1 
# which is importance for convergence of the neural network
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X)

# Split the data set into training and testing
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(
    X_scaled, Y, test_size=0.25, random_state=2, shuffle=True)
```

I trained the CNN model with the shape of X_train = (2120907, 78), y_train = (2120907, 15).

```py
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=DeprecationWarning)

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras import callbacks
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Flatten, Convolution1D, Dropout
from sklearn import metrics
from hyperopt import fmin, hp, tpe, Trials, STATUS_OK
from hyperopt.plotting import main_plot_history, main_plot_vars
import uuid
import gc
from tensorflow import keras
import tensorflow as tf
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution1D(filters=128, kernel_size=6, input_shape=(78, 1)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Convolution1D(filters=256, kernel_size=6))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(15))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.summary() 

tf.keras.utils.plot_model(
    model,
        show_shapes=True,
    show_dtype=False,
      show_layer_names=False,
)


K = keras.backend

nn_history = {}

def train_dynamic_model(args):
    print('\nRun') 
    print('==========')
    print('Parameters:\n{}'.format(args))
    
    batch_size = int(args['batch_size'])
    dropout_rate = args['dropout_rate']
    model_name = '/home/rkalak/hl/model/{}.h5'.format(uuid.uuid4()) 
    opt_name = args['optimizer']['name']

        
    K.clear_session()
    gc.collect()

     

    # Simple 3 Layer Dense Model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(128, input_dim=_features, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.3))
    model.add(Dense(n_classes))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))
    model.summary() 

    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer=opt_name ,metrics=['accuracy'])

    #early_stop_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', patience=5)
    reduce_lr = tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.2,
                                  patience=3, min_lr=0.001)
    
    hist = model.fit(X_train, Y_train,
                              batch_size=batch_size,
                              epochs=350,
                              verbose=True,
                              validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))
                             # ,callbacks=[reduce_lr, early_stop_callback])
    
    nn_history[model_name] = hist.history
    
    y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
    #balanced_score = metrics.balanced_accuracy_score(np.argmax(Y_test, axis=1), y_pred) * 100
    
    best_loss = np.amin(hist.history['val_loss']) 
    print('Best loss: {}'.format(best_loss))
    print('Model: {}'.format(model_name))
    #print('Balanced Acc loss: {}'.format(balanced_score))
    return {
        'loss': best_loss,
        'status': STATUS_OK,
        'model_name': model_name
    }

args = {
    'batch_size': 500,
    'dropout_rate': 0.1,
    'optimizer':
        {
            'name': 'adam',
        }
}
```

and to get the confusion matrix, I have X_test  = (706969, 78), y_test = (2120907, 15).

to get the confusion matrix,I have done it like this,

```py
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
y_pred = np.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)
y_test = np.argmax(Y_test, axis=1)

print(classification_report(y_test,y_pred))
```

the above snippet gives the shape of  y_pred = (706969,)

```py
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.51      0.00      0.00    567846
           1       0.00      0.00      0.00       514
           2       0.08      0.00      0.01     31950
           3       0.00      0.00      0.00      2532
           4       0.08      0.60      0.15     57807
           5       0.00      0.00      0.00      1386
           6       0.01      0.04      0.01      1471
           7       0.00      0.00      0.00      1980
           8       0.00      1.00      0.00         5
           9       0.00      0.00      0.00         9
          10       0.00      0.00      0.00     39460
          11       0.00      0.00      0.00      1480
          12       0.00      0.00      0.00       368
          13       0.00      0.00      0.00         8
          14       0.00      0.00      0.00       153

    accuracy                           0.05    706969
   macro avg       0.05      0.11      0.01    706969
weighted avg       0.42      0.05      0.01    706969
```

I believe that the above classification report is wrong. because When I plot the model, my model produces great accuracy. But when I try to get the classification report out of y_test, y_pred, it's completely strange results.
[image: accuracy image]

so how to get the confusion matrix and classification matrix out of y_pred, y_test

Comment: You can apply argmax to the `y_test` as well. By the way, you have data leak, scaling should be done after the train-test split.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will do scaling on training and testing separately.

Comment: it's not working, I am getting a strange results if use ```np.argmax()``` @Frightera

Comment: Please update the question accordingly, we cannot guess what are the *strange results* .

Answer (score 0):

A **one-hot vector** *is a vector with all 0s and a single 1*. Hence, instead of argmax, you can use **np.where** as follows :

```
import numpy as np  
a  = np.array([[0,1,0,0],[1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1]])
print('np.argmax(a, axis=1): {0}'.format(np.argmax(a, axis=1)))
```

Output -

```
np.argmax(a, axis=1): [1 0 3]
```

With np.where,

```
[np.where(r==1)[0][0] for r in a]
```

Output :

```
[1, 0, 3]
```

Coming to confusion matrix , here are the steps to do that with **Keras CNN** :

##### Confusion Matrix with CNN

##### 1. Predict Classes

```
test_generator = ImageDataGenerator()
test_data_generator = test_generator.flow_from_directory(
    test_data_path, # Put your path here
     target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=32,
    shuffle=False)
test_steps_per_epoch = numpy.math.ceil(test_data_generator.samples / test_data_generator.batch_size)

predictions = model.predict_generator(test_data_generator, steps=test_steps_per_epoch)
#Get most likely class
predicted_classes = numpy.argmax(predictions, axis=1)
```

##### 2. Get True Values of classes,label

```
true_classes = test_data_generator.classes
class_labels = list(test_data_generator.class_indices.keys())
```

##### 3. Get matrix

```
report = metrics.classification_report(true_classes, predicted_classes, target_names=class_labels)
print(report)
```